# rails fill out the field from validate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set the date field (which type is datetime ) with following code:

```
class News < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :set_date 


  def set_date
    self.date = created_at.strftime('%Y-%d-%m')
  end
end
```

db.schema has t.datetime: date field 
and I check this from rails console

`News.create(title: 'title3', content: 'contenta abrakadabra3')`

News is created properly, but the date field is nil. Why is that?

News id: 4, date: nil, title: "title3", content: "contenta abrakadabra3", sources: nil, created_at: "2017-07-27 11:49:12", updated_at: "2017-07-27 11:49:12">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in a String and the date field expects a DateTime.

```
class News < ApplicationRecord
  before_action :set_date 


  def set_date
    self.date = created_at
  end
end
```

If you wish to save only the date. create a migration

```
class ChangeDateFormatInNews < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
   change_column :news, :date, :datetime
  end

  def down
   change_column :news, :date, :date
  end
end
```

Then in your model

```
class News < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :set_date 


  def set_date
    self.date = created_at.to_date
  end
end
```

Comment: ```date``` already  has Datetime type. I don't need migration, yes you're right I'd like to store my date as date without time. And when I did it in rails console after create it's ok.  News id: 10, date: "2017-07-27", title: "title12", content: "contenta abrakadabra12", sources: nil, created_at: "2017-07-27 12:40:36", updated_at: "2017-07-27 12:40:36"

Comment: Then I tried to show just date in rails console and there I see ```nil``` again.

Comment: you need save after you set date

Comment: thanks dendomenko, indeed i'm used to this in a before action :). You can also save this in the set_date method.

Answer (score 0):

`strftime` will convert your time object to string. I guess you want to store it as date. For that you should use `to_date`

```
class News < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :set_date 


  def set_date
    self.date = created_at.to_date
  end
end
```